# How "STAR" not considered as a Quantifier in regular expersion?

Tags: java, regular-language

There is no problem for the following model of IP(for example) :

```
255.3.3.6
```

by this RE(from: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-ip-address-with-regular-expression/):

```
   "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +

    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +

    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +

    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
```

but I want to have an IP-pattern to handle one IP like following model:

```
255.*.3.100
```

OR

```
*.*.3.100
```

OR

```
*.*.*.*
```

(any places in the IP, can be a star)

i use this pattern:

```
         "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.|(\\*)\\." +
         "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.|(\\*)\\." +
         "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.|(\\*)\\." +
         "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])|(\\*)\\.$";
```

but it dose not work.

I think star in my pattern considered as one Quantifier .
what should I do?please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk is an additional alternative. Compose without repetitions.

```
String group = "(?:[01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]|\\*)";
String patstr = "^" + group + "(\\." + group + "){3}$";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( patstr );
Matcher mat = pat.matcher( args[0] );
System.out.println( mat.matches() );
```

The grammar represented by OP's regular expression can be written as

```
IP ::= DP
      |APDP
      |APDP
      |APD
      |AP
D ::= Number
P ::= '.'
A ::= '*'
```

Note that the operator `|` separates alternatives; thus no valid address is matching, and no address where a number is replaced by an asterisk.

Comment: It's perfect answer.tank u "laune".